# Grails rendering JSON from domain list weird behaviour

Tags: json, grails

I'm trying to return JSON from a controller action. This is my action method

```
import grails.converters.JSON
....    
def getDoctorList(id){

    def serviceNo = id ?: "1"


    def service = ServicePoint.findByNumber(serviceNo)

    def jsonMap=service?.staff.collect{
         [id: it.id , name: it.firstName +" "+ it.lastName]             
    }

    render jsonMap as JSON

   }
```

If I convert jsonMap to JSON in the last line my page will not be rendered and If I removed as JSON page rendered and everything works fine. What is wrong with this code?

=================================================================================

I don't need to render a gsp page I need to render the map as json to use it in filling a drop box in a gsp page. Now pages that are rendered by ajax is not shown when I use (as JSON) in the code. If I remove it everything works fine.

Comment: What do you mean with "my page will not be rendered" ? What do you expect and what happens?

Answer (score 1):

By rendering JSON, you're not rendering the template associated with the action.  If I assume convention and you have a getDoctorList.gsp, then the following would work:

```
def getDoctorList(id){
 //.. logic here
 // leaving no render method will default to convention
 // rendering getDoctorList.gsp
}

def getDoctorList(id){
 //.. logic here
 // supplying a render with a view will render that view
 render view: 'doctor_list' // assumes doctor_list.gsp
}

def getDoctorList(id){
 //.. logic here
 // Rendering JSON will not use a template at all
 render jsonMap as JSON
}
```

This would work, but I doubt it is what you want:

```
def getDoctorList(id){
 //.. logic here
 [jsonMap: jsonMap as JSON]
}
```

That would push the jsonMap as a request param to the getDoctorList.gsp.  Generally speaking, rendering JSON data is usually in response to an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Not `render jsonMap as JSON`, but `return jsonMap as JSON`. In first case, you're returning `text/html` in `Content-type` header, with `return` Grails sets it to `application/json`.